# Trying to publish a JSON message to a pub/sub Topic

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, terraform-provider-gcp

I can easily [publish a message](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#console) manually with JSON format in a pub/sub Topic using Console (GUI) as shown bellow and no error in my Cloud Function logs and works well.

Message:

> {"account": "gcp", "key":
> "projects/xxxxxx/secrets/my-secret-v2/v/2"}

But I want to do it in my terraform code to publish this JSON message format and not sure if this is possible to do it with Terraform. Also, I've tried it with gcloud command but I've found a error message that can't read JSON format in the Cloud Function logs .

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish MY_TOPIC --message '{"account": "gcp", "key": "projects/xxxxxx/secrets/my-secret-v2/v/2"}'
```

This is the error in Cloud Function logs:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

My question is how can I publish this JSON format message via Terraform or gcloud?

My Terraform code:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "topic" {
name = var.topic
project = var.project
```

Subscription:

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "pubsub_subscription" {
name  = var.pubsub_subscription
topic = google_pubsub_topic.topic.name
project = var.project


message_retention_duration = "86400s"      
retain_acked_messages      = false         
enable_message_ordering    = true      

ack_deadline_seconds = 10               

expiration_policy {                  
  ttl = ""

}
```

Cloud Function:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "function_gcp" {
  project     = var.project
  region    = "northamerica-northeast1"
  name        = "testing"
  description = "GCP Test"
  runtime     = "python39"
  event_trigger {
    event_type = "google.pubsub.topic.publish"
    resource   = "projects/${var.project}/topics/${google_pubsub_topic.topic.name}"
  }
    available_memory_mb   = 256
    source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
    source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.code.name
    service_account_email = google_service_account.email
    entry_point           = "python-file"
    labels = {
      "application" : "my-application",
      "source" : "terraform"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the terraform code you have?

Comment: It would also be good to see the Cloud Function code that is presumably the code on the subscriber side.

Comment: Question is updated and added tf codes

Comment: question is how can I add my JSON message to my tf codes  or even how can I publish it using gcloud!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by adding """ to the JSON message.

```
{"""account""": """gcp""", """key""": """projects/xxxxxx/secrets/my-secret-v2/v/2"""}
```